# Bootstrap3 : popover does not appear initially when initiated by click event of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been trying to show a popover when any element of a common class is clicked on the body. The problem is that, the popover does not appear initially at the first click, but it appears and behaves normally from the next click events. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info pop" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Hello World! This is a test!"> Popover on top </button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('body').on('click', '.pop', function(e){
    $(this).popover();//.popover('show');
});
```

It is also available in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tanvir442/18n5y15o/2/).

I can not figure out what is wrong here? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functional code would be:

```
$( '.pop' ).popover();
```

[Forked your fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/18n5y15o/11/).

Initializing `popover` on an element handles click events itself. Your code waited for the first click to initialize the popover behaviour, which meant the second click was the first that the popover could handle itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise the plugin on page load, not on click.

Change your code to this:

`$('.pop').popover();`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/18n5y15o/10/)

If this is an element that is added to the page after load, you will need to initialise the plugin after the element is created.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing it, is through popover options, as you can see on [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers)

Could be something like this:

```
$('.pop').popover( { container: 'body', placement: 'top', trigger: 'click' } );
```

As you can see, you can specify here multiple options, like where to append it, placement or trigger.

Note, you must include this on a document ready block.

[Here is a jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/18n5y15o/15/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to call destroy before showing.Following code will work for you

```
$(document).on("click", ".pop", function(){

    $(this).popover("destroy");

    $(this).popover({
        placement: 'top',
        html: true,
        title: "Popover Title",
        content: "<strong>Popover Content</strong>"
    });

    $(this).popover("show");
});
```

Comment: I liked your concept, but it does not toggle once it is clicked.